# Google maps not always fully rendering in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Having trouble with always rendering google maps in my Ionic app. When I first land on a view from a list of items on the previous view, the map always renders in its complete state. However, if I go back to the previous view and tap a different business, or even the same one, it appears as if the map is only rendering 25% of the complete map. I'm having this issue on both the emulator and on my iPhone.

**Example**

[image]

**Code**

```
getData.getBusinesses()
    .then(function(data) {
        // get businesses data from getData factory
    })
    .then(function(data) {
        // get businesses photo from getData factory
    })
    .then(function(data) {
        // get some other business stuff
    })
    .then(function() {
        // get reviews for current business from separate async call in reviews factory
    })
    .then(function() {
        // instantiate our map
        var map = new GoogleMap($scope.business.name, $scope.business.addr1, $scope.business.city, $scope.business.state, $scope.business.zip, $scope.business.lat, $scope.business.long);
        map.initialize();
    })
    .then(function() {
        // okay, hide loading icon and show view now
    },
    function(err) {
        // log an error if something goes wrong
    });
```

What doesn't make sense to me is that I'm using this exact code for a website equivalent of the app, yet the maps fully load in the browser every time. The maps also fully load when I do an `ionic serve` and test the app in Chrome. I did also try returning the map and initializing it in a following promise, but to no avail.

I've also tried using [angular google maps](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/), but the same issue is occurring. I think I might want to refactor my **gmaps.js** (where I'm creating the Google Maps function) into a directive, but I don't know if that will actually fix anything (seeing as angular google maps had the same rendering issue).

I don't think the full code is necessary, but if you need to see more let me know.

**EDIT**

It seems that wrapping my map call in a `setTimeout` for 100ms always renders the map now. So I guess the new question is, what's the angular way of doing this?

Comment: @Darnn found a solution?

Comment: @JulioMarins Only thing I could come up with is wrapping the map init in a setTimeout for 500ms, probably not the best way to do it, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing similar issues with [ng-map](http://ngmap.github.io/) in Ionic.  I have a map inside of a tab view and upon switching tabs away from the map view and back again, I would often see the poorly rendered and greyed out map as you describe above.  Two things that I did that may help fix your issue:

1. Try using `$state.go('yourStateHere', {}, {reload: true});` to get back to your view.  The `reload: true` seemed to help re-render the map properly when the map was within the tab's template.
2. After wrapping the map in my own directive, I found the same thing happening again and wasn't able to fix it with the first suggestion.  To fix it this time, I started with [@Fernando's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30563418/266426) and added his suggested `$ionicView.enter` event to my directive's controller.  When that didn't work, I instead added a simple `ng-if="vm.displayMap"` directive to the `<ng-map>` directive and added the following code to add it to the DOM on controller activation and remove it from the DOM right before leaving the view.

   ```
   function controller($scope) {
       vm.displayMap = true;
       $scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeLeave', function(){
           vm.displayMap = false;
       });
   }
   ```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

don't use setTimeout on this!
You need to understand that the map is conflicting with the container size or something (example: map is loading while ionic animation is running, like swiping).

Once you understand this, you need to set map after view is completely rendered.
Try this on your controller:

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(){
        var map = new GoogleMap($scope.business.name, 
                                $scope.business.addr1, $scope.business.city, 
                                $scope.business.state, $scope.business.zip,
                                $scope.business.lat, $scope.business.long);
        map.initialize();
});
```